# View.getDrawingCache() with background for semi-transparent view

Tags: android, android-view

Is it possible to get the drawing cache with the views behind the view? For example, I have a semi-transparent view and I can see views behind it. So, can I get the drawing cache of this view with the behind views visible?

Code where I'm adding the view to WM:

```
 final View screenshotView = new View(this) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
                        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

                        if (!changed) {
                            buildDrawingCache();
                            final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getDrawingCache());
                            final File file = new File("/sdcard/test.png");
                            try {
                                file.createNewFile();
                                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                                ostream.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

WindowManager.LayoutParams screenShotViewLp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
                screenShotViewLp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                screenShotViewLp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                screenShotViewLp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;

                wm.addView(screenshotView, screenShotViewLp);
```

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT]** according to last edits of the question I think this answer doesn't fit anymore. Adding a view directly to the WindowManager infact leads the discussion to a well-known problem: taking a screenshot programmatically in Android is not allowed, and then the idea exposed below seems totally impractical.
So please don't undervote.**[/EDIT]**

AFAIK this can't be achieved via the drawingCache of the single view. In order to get also the other views on the background you should take the drawingCache of the topmost node in the view tree, that is the content of the containing Activity. Getting such a bitmap is quite simple:

```
View root = currActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmp = root.getDrawingCache();
```

Then, in order to get only the portion of bitmap you are interested in, you are forced to crop the generated bitmap according to `View.getLocatonInWindow(int[])` values.

Haven't proved myself, but I'm quite confident it should work.

Comment: My view is added from service directly to WindowManager without activity

Comment: This complicates things a little :) Can you post the code used to attach the view to the `WindowManager`?

Comment: I think this _detail_ makes the approach above totally impractical. I updated my answer accordingly.